# Error 'Can't assign to operator' using Python 3.4.3

Tags: python, operator-keyword, assign

The following is my script, and I keep getting the error:

> Can't assign to operator

#### Code

```
nine = 9
ten = 12
nine + ten = 21
print (" Hello, this is going to test your mathematical ability.")
print ("What is nine + ten?")
if 21 == nine + ten:
    print ("You're stupid")
else:
    print ("You're wrong!")
```

I'm really new and stuff to Python, so please explain the code clearly.

Comment: Indentation / proper formatting please

Comment: What did you expect `nine + ten = 21` to do?

Comment: `ten = 12` You must like brain-teasers.

Comment: Well it all works out in base 12, but apparently the OP doesn't like base 12 people, as they are called out for being stupid when in fact they are correct in their native base!

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that your code looks like this;

```
nine = 9
ten = 12
nine + ten = 21

print (" Hello, this is going to test your mathematical ability")
print ("what is nine + ten?")

if 21 == nine + ten:
    print ("you stupid")
else:
    print ("you're wrong!")
```

On line 3, you're assigning "nine + ten" to the value 21. This is not valid syntax and is giving you your error.

Even if this was valid syntax, your code will always print "you stupid" as  nine + ten will always have the value 21.